# Deleting images obtained by ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents on API level < 30

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm finding myself incapable of deleting images, the Uri's of which are being obtained via `ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents()` on API level < 29. As opposed to using the deprecated way of making the user select images via

```
startActivityForResult(
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
                .apply {
                    type = MimeTypes.IMAGE
                    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
                },
            someIntentCode
        )
```

, `ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents()` invokes this more generic file explorer, rather than merely opening the gallery, which then after the actual image selection results in document Uris along the lines of `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A101`. Now, on API >= 30 I feed the Uri's into a delete request via

```
MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(
                contentResolver,
                deletionQueryImageUris
            )
```

, which upon the user then confirming the deletion works just fine, on APIs lower than that I wasn't so lucky tho.

`DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(contentResolver, documentUri)` fails with

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing
> com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri
> content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A101
> from pid=24476, uid=10090 requires
> android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()

, while I neither manage to convert the documentUri to a mediaUri, to then delete it via

```
contentResolver.delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                       "${MediaStore.Images.Media._ID}=?",
                       arrayOf(queryMediaStoreColumn(uri, mediaColumn = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)))
```

since `MediaStore.getMediaUri(context, documentUri)` also requires API level 29.

Note that `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is already granted.

Thanks in advance for whatever kind of help.

Comment: "which I in and itself already don't quite get, since, the way I see it, those two ways of doing it emit the exact same Intent under the hood" -- that is incorrect. `GetMultipleContents()` uses `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, not `ACTION_PICK`. "As opposed to using the deprecated way of making the user select images" -- [`ACTION_PICK` is not deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PICK) as of Android 13.

Comment: 1.: Alright, thanks for clearing that up for me.
2.: startActivityForResult is tho, isn't it?

And I'd like to use the new ActivityResultContracts API in any case.

Comment: So, [use `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult).

Comment: Okay cool man, thanks for your incredibly useful phrasing loophole finding. I still want to delete images corresponding to uris, obtained by means of 
registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents()){ uris ->}.launch("image/*") tho. Let me know if that way of stating it still comprises any ambiguities.